# Handling drop down lists with large amount of items in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a question about amount of items in a drop down lists. I'm not asking about the UX but technical efficiency. I'm going to prepare drop down list filtered with value in a text box above it.

- What's the amount of items which should disqualify that solution.
  1000, 2000, 10000?
- Should I load all the data into some hidden html element or on every change of text box make ajax call to server and get filtered data?

Let's assume it's an intranet desktop web application running on IE.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not asking about the UX but technical efficiency. What's the amount of items which should disqualify that solution. 1000, 2000, 10000?

That is the wrong question. It may be workable with 10,000 items on your machine, 2000 on mine and 50 on a mobile browser, but again, that is not the question you need answered.

Negating the UX question: just use an existing AutoComplete textbox with according dropdown, and load enough items so you can fill the relevant portion of the screen. This may be about 10-25 items, depending on your layout.

Comment: Okay, but what amount of data would kill the browser (namely IE, desktop) for sure. I'm not talking about exact number, but approximate - 10k, 100k, 1M? And what about loading process, better load everything to HTML and filter using java script or on each textbox change get filtered data from server?